# Ionic: cordova-plugin-inappbrowser set default target

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, browser, inappbrowser

Hello fellow programmers,

I've been experiencing a problem with the in-app-browser plugin. The reason is that I'm not able to give the target manually everytime te browser opens. This is because sometimes users fill in a link to their website inside a textfield.

Afterwards I was looking for a option to set a "default" option like (system, blank, ect.) But I wasn't able to find anything suitable.

I hope you guys can help me with this problem!

Greetings

Comment: Do you mean that you would like to override all hyperlinks so that they are opened with the InAppBrowser with your specified target?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Cordova Documents at this link](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/) shows what options can be used.

Target: The target in which to load the URL, an optional parameter that defaults to _self. (String)

**_self:** Opens in the Cordova WebView if the URL is in the white list, 
otherwise it opens in the InAppBrowser.

**_blank:** Opens in the InAppBrowser.

**_system:** Opens in the system's web browser.

Here is an example from my code to open an in app browser or the system browser.

```
$('#btnVisitToday').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    window.open('http://www.sample.com', '_system');
});
```

I use _system to open up Google Play (have not tried it with app store)

Comment: This is not really what I meant. Because my app users fill the website link in a description I can't do a "window.open" action. If you click on the link the website will just open. It is probably a <a href="" ...

Comment: Giovanni, see the update I posted in my answer. Using Cordova I call the function window.open on user action, you can do that with a URL they key in as well vs. a href...

Comment: In your updated post I assume that you're using jQuery to do the action. My only problem is that I am not using jQuery in my ionic application, so this would be no solution for me.